# PowerShell - Copy-item with -passThru to post process files

Tags: powershell

Newbie stuck doing the basics.

I'm trying to copy files from A to B & then replace text within each file copied. Pretty basic - but it fails What am I doing wrong? Any assistance would be welcome - please. nb I believe I need to use copy-item, alternatives okay as long as same result.

```
$files = Copy-Item -Path "C:\from" -Filter *.* -Recurse -Destination "C:\to" -Force -PassThru

foreach ($file in $files) { 

     Get-Item $file | 
     Where-Object {-not $_.PsIsContainer} | 
     (Get-Content .) | 
     Foreach-Object {
         $_ -replace ( "maskkey", $maskvalue} |                          
         Set-Content $file 
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the get-content part within the foreach-object script block, and use $_ instead of .

So, something like this:

```
foreach($file in $files){
    Get-Item $file | Where-Object {-not ($_.PsIsContainer)} | Foreach-Object{
        $content = Get-Content $_
        $newContent = $content.replace("maskkey", $maskvalue)
        Set-Content -Value $newContent -Path $file
    }
}
```

Note. I haven't actually tested this code, but you should at least have the basic structure right.

Comment: Ah, I see what I did wrong, I made your change but kept the pipe format - Thanks